# How can we do overloading in php?

Tags: php, javascript

In java we call it overloading when we define two methods with different numbers of arguments.How do we do it in php or javascript where number of parameters passed need not be equal to arguments defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript:

```
function testing(){
     console.log(arguments);//<-- all func args
}
```

PHP:

```
function testing(){
    var_dump(func_get_args());//<-- all func args
}
```

Comment: But you "cannot" (E_STRICT error) overload a method in PHP (without using func_get_args()) when the original one has other parameters than the new one.

Comment: and you can test the type of the passed argument if reqd. `typeof`  in JavaScript or `is_type()` in PHP.

Comment: thanks this is cool. Knew it but couldnt relate it to java way was thinking that more than one methods will be required.

Comment: @sushil -- why would you want more than one method?

Comment: @neal i am in complete agreement with you know. My java days were hanging over me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Neal Because that is the 'normal' way you overload methods. You can't strictly overload methods in PHP or JavaScript. This is just a workaround.

Comment: @w3d: You mean [gettype()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.gettype.php)? You should rather use is_*() (e.g. is_array()) to check for a specific type! See the warning in the manual.

Comment: @user603003 I meant `is_bool()`, `is_string()`, `is_int()`, etc. I was trying to refer to this generically as is_type() but that didn't come across in the formatting, `is_*()` is better - thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign default values to the parameters like so:

```
function example(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
  //Do something
}

example(10, 5);
```

Comment: ... only in PHP, not JavaScript

Comment: Ah yes, sry, in javascript I believe you can just specify the parameters and then test if they have been assigned values in the body of the function.